# Flatten is not exploding rows in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Input

| Policy | break_down |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | "[{Business/Corporation 49 0.5145} {Corporate Formation 5 0.06999999999999999} {Taxation 1 0.0105} {Estate/Trust/Probate 45 0.5625}]" |
| 234 | null |

Is the expected output 4 rows as below (since it has 4 values in the list):

Expected output

| policy | Description | Pricing_Mod_Factor | Pricing Mod Premium |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234. | Business/Corporation | 49 | 0.5145 |
| 1234. | Corporate Formation | 5 | 0.06999999999999999 |
| 1234. | Taxation | 10 | 0.0105 |
| 1234 | Estate/Trust/Probate | 45 | 0.5625 |

**Query:**

```
with temp as (
    select  
        b.id,  
        (replace(get(rater_response:rate_breakdown:coverage_output_list,0):factor_breakdown:
     per_attorney_premium:lookup_values ,'"','') ) as arr1
     --b.*,c.insurance_application_id
    from rater b
)
SELECT 
    id,
    flattened_data.value
     /*substring(replace(split(flattened_data.value, '}')[0],'[{',''),1, REGEXP_INSTR(replace(split(flattened_data.value, '}')[0],'[{',''),'\\d')-2) as col1, */
FROM temp,
```

Comment: Hi, neither your input or output column names seem to match up with your SQL. In your SQL, the column names in the CTE don’t match with your main query, you don’t seem to be using FLATTEN - so your whole question makes little sense - and I’ve no idea what the “get” function in your SQL is. If you can provide proper input and output data and SQL that at least works (even if I’d doesn’t give the result you want) then someone may be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so with your example data in a CTE to make it simple to test:

```
with policies(id, break_down ) as (
    select * from values
    (1234, '[{Business/Corporation 49 0.5145} {Corporate Formation 5 0.06999999999999999} {Taxation 1 0.0105} {Estate/Trust/Probate 45 0.5625}]'),
    (234,   null)
)
select
    *
from policies as p
,table(split_to_table(trim(p.break_down, '[]'),'}' )) as s
```

using [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table) we can do a token based split of this strings as it is not valid JSON. Here I am using the end wiggle bracket as the split maker. This gives the output:

[image]

Now we can clean that result up a little more:

```
select
    p.id
    ,trim(s.value,' {') as val
from policies as p
,table(split_to_table(trim(p.break_down, '[]'),'}' )) as s
where val is not null and val <> ''
```

gives: us the flattened data:

[image]

then pulling those appart:

```
with policies(id, break_down ) as (
    select * from values
    (1234, '[{Business/Corporation 49 0.5145} {Corporate Formation 5 0.06999999999999999} {Taxation 1 0.0105} {Estate/Trust/Probate 45 0.5625}]'),
    (234,   null)
), flattened_policies as (
    select
        p.id
        ,trim(s.value,' {') as val
    from policies as p
    ,table(split_to_table(trim(p.break_down, '[]'),'}' )) as s
    where val is not null and val <> ''
)
select
    id
    ,strtok_to_array(val, ' ') as parts
    ,array_size(parts) as parts_len
    ,array_to_string(array_slice(parts, 0, parts_len -2), ' ') as desc
    ,parts[parts_len -2]::number as factor
    ,parts[parts_len -1]::double as premium
from flattened_policies as fp
```

gives:

[image]

and now we can clean that up:

```
with policies(id, break_down ) as (
    select * from values
    (1234, '[{Business/Corporation 49 0.5145} {Corporate Formation 5 0.06999999999999999} {Taxation 1 0.0105} {Estate/Trust/Probate 45 0.5625}]'),
    (234,   null)
), flattened_policies as (
    select
        p.id
        ,trim(s.value,' {') as val
    from policies as p
    ,table(split_to_table(trim(p.break_down, '[]'),'}' )) as s
    where val is not null and val <> ''
), pulled_appart as (
select
        id
        ,strtok_to_array(val, ' ') as parts
        ,array_size(parts) as parts_len
        ,array_to_string(array_slice(parts, 0, parts_len -2), ' ') as desc
        ,parts[parts_len -2]::number as factor
        ,parts[parts_len -1]::double as premium
    from flattened_policies as fp
)
select * exclude (parts, parts_len)
from pulled_appart;
```

gives:

| ID | DESC | FACTOR | PREMIUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Business/Corporation | 49 | 0.5145 |
| 1234 | Corporate Formation | 5 | 0.07 |
| 1234 | Taxation | 1 | 0.0105 |
| 1234 | Estate/Trust/Probate | 45 | 0.5625 |